# Parsing XML in Python using LXML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

```
tree = etree.parse("pinnacle_feed.xml")

fdtime = tree.xpath('//rsp/fd/fdTime/text()')
global lasttime 
lasttime = fdtime[0]


for leagues in tree.getiterator('league'):
    leagueid = tree.xpath('//id/text()')

    for elt in leagues.getiterator('event'):
        startDateTime = elt.xpath('//startDateTime/text()')
        eventId = elt.xpath('//id/text()')
        homeTeam = elt.xpath('./homeTeam/name/text()')
        awayTeam = elt.xpath('./awayTeam/name/text()')
        homeTeamOdds = elt.xpath('./periods/period/moneyLine/homePrice/text()')
        awayTeamOdds = elt.xpath('./periods/period/moneyLine/awayPrice/text()')
        drawOdds = elt.xpath('./periods/period/moneyLine/drawPrice/text()')
        print full_iterator
```

That is the code I am currently using. The issue is, I need to find out the 'current' leagueid as it is needed when I parse through the events in that league.

```
leagueid = tree.xpath('//id/text()')
```

returns a list of all the leagueids and not just the 'current one'

I hope I explained myself correctly and someone could give me a hand/advice.

XML doc: http://pastebin.com/BDaJ7Ayx

Comment: Please post your XML, otherwise we have no idea how to help.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is http://pastebin.com/BDaJ7Ayx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need to get the id from current node referenced by `leagues` variable :

```
leagueid = leagues.xpath('./id/text()')
```

Above Xpath looks for child node `<id>` from current `<league>` node.

Comment: Alternatively, the OP can explicitly define the league node in xpath: `leagueid = tree.xpath('//league/id/text()')`

Comment: @Parfait Your XPath should work for sample XML given, but in case there are multiple `<league>` nodes, `//league/id/text()` will return all ids instead of id of current league

Comment: Thank you har07! Works a treat